# checking whether representation of number in a given base is valid

Tags: python, numbers, radix, representation

i have written this code which checks whether a number is correctly represented in a given base. for all the invalid cases it gives false but for true ones it says string index out of range.

```
def check(n,a,i=0):
    if int(n[i])>=a :
        return False
    else:
        return check(n,a,i+1)   
n = str(input('enter no:'))
a =int(input('enter base:'))
print(check(n,a,i=0))
```

Comment: Your recursion has no base case that returns `True`. `i` just keeps getting larger until it goes out of range. You need a test for when it goes out of range and when it does, return `True` instead of calling `check` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ooga pointed out, you need to check when `i` is larger than the length of your number, you can make it like:

```
def check(n,a,i=0):
    if len(n) <= i:
        return True
    if int(n[i])>=a :
        return False
    else:
        return check(n,a,i+1)   

n = str(input('enter no:'))
a = int(input('enter base:'))

print(check(n,a,i=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way:

```
def is_base_x(num_string, base):
    for single_char in num_string:
        if int(single_char) >= int(base):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if it could check bases above 10. Something like this:

```
import string

def check(num, base, i = 0):
    if i >= len(num):
        return True
    if not num[i].isdigit():
        val = string.ascii_lowercase.find(num[i].lower())
        if val == -1 or val + 10 >= base:
            return False
    elif int(num[i]) >= base:
        return False
    return check(num, base, i + 1)

while True:
    num = raw_input('Enter number: ')
    if len(num) == 0: break # null string breaks
    base = int(raw_input('Enter base: '))
    print(check(num, base))
```